# AJAX live search returning HTTP 500 error

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I get a 500 Internal Server Error when I use live search.

Html code:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 ">
    <div class="header-search-block ">
         <input type="text" name="search" id="search"
                placeholder="@lang('index.Type here to search')">
         <button>@lang('index.Search')</button>
    </div>
    <div id="result">
         <span>results is here</span>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Ajax code:

```js
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#result").hide();
        $("input[name=search]").keyup(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            var data = "value=" + value;
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                data: data,
                url: '{{URL::to('search')}}',
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#result").show().html(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

My controller:

```php
public function search(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {

    $currentLangKey = session()->get('language') ?? App::getLocale();
    $languageId = Language::whereNull('deleted_at')->where('name', $currentLangKey)->first()->id ?? 0;


    $search = mb_strtolower($request->get('search'));
    $bookSearch = DB::table('books')->select('id', 'name', 'category_id', 'collection_id', 'price',
        'cover', 'seller', 'publisher',
        DB::raw("(SELECT name FROM categories WHERE id = category_id) as category_name"),
        DB::raw("COALESCE((SELECT AVG(star) FROM comments WHERE book_id = books.id), 5) as star_average"),
        DB::raw("(SELECT name FROM collections WHERE id = collection_id) as collection_name"))
        ->where(DB::raw('lower(name)'), 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->where('language_id', $languageId)
        ->paginate(16);

    return response()->json($bookSearch);

}
```

Comment: As long as your laravel config has debug turned on, look in your browser dev tools at the network request and you should see your PHP error there in the response tab.

Comment: I get a 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors#configuration

Comment: Most importantly, use a prepared query in your `where()` - you're open to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The search string is sent to your server through `value` attribute

```
//...
$("input[name=search]").keyup(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            var data = "value=" + value;
//...
```

Fix

```
$search = mb_strtolower($request->get('value'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a couple of things. First is change you post type in ajax from get to post. Second is change the value of $search to $request->value which you are sending using Ajax

```
<script>
  $(function () {
       $("#result").hide();
       $("input[name=search]").keyup(function () {
           var value = $(this).val();
           var data = {’value’ :value};
           $.ajax({
               type: "Post”,
               data: data,
               url: '{{URL::to('search')}}',
               success: function (response) {
                   $("#result").show().html(response);
                }
             });
         });
     });
  </script>
```